# WPF - Treeview and ContentControl virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contentcontrol

I have a treeview with itemsource containing items of custom class TreeviewItem.

I have a property SelectedTreeviewItemViewModel of type TreeviewItem.

```
public TreeviewItem SelectedTreeviewItemViewModel //with INPC
```

I have a content control somewhere else on the window

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedTreeviewItemViewModel}" />
```

with a datatemplate as follow:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeviewItem}">
        <uc:TreeviewCustomView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

When I click on an item of the treeview, the event SelectedItemChanged is fired and I set SelectedTreeviewItemViewModel which forces the contentcontrol to refresh its content.

The logic is fine, however I noticed that when I click on a new item in the treeview, some data is updated but I don't step into the user control's constructor (uc:TreeviewCustomView).

Is there some kind of virtualization involved? I'm guessing WPF caches the datatemplate; is there any way I can force WPF to recreate the user control from scratch (thus stepping into the constructor) everytime I click on a treeview item?

Answer (score 1):

TreeViews are virtualized by default when using binding.
If you switch the mode to VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" instead of "Recycling" the constructor should get called.

Comment: The problem is not located within the treeview. I can for the virtualization mode but it won't do me any good: the problem is located within the content control which seems to cache the data temple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what did the trick for me:

I create a template selector which basically wraps the template in another template, forcing the creation of a new instance.
Please keep in mind that this can result in severe perf problems!

In my xaml, I start by naming the data template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeviewItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type TreeviewItem}">
        <uc:TreeviewCustomView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then I create a template selector as follow:

```
public class TreeviewItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var declaredDataTemplate = ((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource("TreeviewItemTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        var wrappedDataTemplate = WrapDataTemplate(declaredDataTemplate );
        return wrappedDataTemplate;
    }

    private static DataTemplate WrapDataTemplate(DataTemplate declaredDataTemplate)
    {
        var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
        frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, declaredDataTemplate);
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
        return dataTemplate;
    }
}
```

And finally, I use the selector on my content control:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedTreeviewItemViewModel }"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeviewItemTemplateSelector }" />
```